# Import an external resource to grunt

Tags: gruntjs, external, cdn, concatenation, gulp

I'm trying to import an external resource into gruntfile.js with concat. But dont seem to get my head around it. I've been googling around but only information I found is how to cdnify the solution.

The thing is that we use modules on an CDN and would like to just define the CDN resource instead of download from repo and link locally.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: [
                'https://test.com/cdn/waypoints.js',
                'https://test.com/plugins/hashchange/hashchange-1.4.js',
                'js/ssp-stickit-1.js',
                'js/global.js', 
            ],
            dest: 'js/scripts.js',
        }
    },

}
```

If anyone know if this is possible with gulp, thats an option as well....

Best regards

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a task that first downloads the resource and then concats. But that begs the question, why use a CDN script? CDNs are generally used for common resources that a client might already have cached. If you concat the file, you're no longer taking advantage of that caching. In which, you should probably utilize the script's public outlet, such as npm, bower, component, github, etc.

But if you still want to do it, here is a task/example that downloads and concats:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  urlconcat: {
    all: {
      src: [
        'https://test.com/cdn/waypoints.js',
        'https://test.com/plugins/hashchange/hashchange-1.4.js',
        'js/ssp-stickit-1.js',
        'js/global.js', 
      ],
      dest: 'js/scripts.js',
    },
  },
});

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

grunt.registerMultiTask('urlconcat', function() {
  var done = this.async();
  var options = this.options({
    separator: '\n',
  });
  async.eachSeries(this.files, function(file, next) {
    var out = '';
    async.eachSeries(file.orig.src, function(url, nextUrl) {
      if (grunt.file.exists(url)) {
        // If a file
        grunt.log.writeln('Concatenating ' + url);
        out += grunt.file.read(url) + options.separator;
        nextUrl();
      } else {
        // Otherwise assume a url
        grunt.log.writeln('Downloading ' + url);
        request(url).on('data', function(data) {
          out += data.toString();
        }).on('end', function() {
          out += options.separator;
          nextUrl();
        });
      }
    }, function() {
      grunt.file.write(file.dest, out);
      grunt.log.ok('Wrote ' + file.dest + '.');
      next();
    });
  }, done);
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['urlconcat']);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. The reason that we want to base the scripts on cdn is that we are several people that work on different snippets. This is commited to a GIT repo that is also a CDN server. Then instead of haveing to update all repos locally when we want to include a snippet, we just simply refer to the CDN instead. Maybe this is just stupid, but it feels like it will save us alot of time.

Comment: To use module above you (I) needed to install request (npm install request) and async (npm install async).